# Android - Parental Control Blocking Play Store Purchase

Tags: android

I installed the parental control app [kid's place](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiddoware.kidsplace) from the play store and I am curious how it is able to implement blocking marketplace purchases ?

During test when I try to purchase an item, an Activity from the parental app comes up (the game is still running), but then it takes to the parental control app.

Does anyone know how Google Play Store purchase can be blocked ? (In its demo video this feature is shown at time 1:15)